# HE3D-XI3 3D printer Repetier software config help!

Tags: ramps-1.4, software, prusa-i3

I am new to 3d printing and had bought my first 3d printer a couple of months ago. I have it all put together and the software uploaded to the Arduino. However, I need some help with configuration and calibration of the printer. I understand that there is a configuration file that can be changed and uploaded again the create those changes. I also have worked with Arduino before so I know the IDE.

When I turn the printer on everything works, as far as I know. I did some tests to see if anything was wrong, but I couldn't find anything. However, when I hit *home* for all of the x, y and z axis to go to their starting marks, it tries to go past the rails and comes apart. From what I understand this is a configuration issue.

I tried to contact HE3D about this, but received no answer, so you guys are my last hope. If you need any more information to help me, let me know and i'll try getting it to you asap. (I also have read the documentation on Repetier and the installation and configuration section but my brain for some reason is not clicking into gear.)

Thanks for the help in advanced!!! Here are the specs:
https://www.3dprintersonlinestore.com/reprap-prusa-xi3

Comment: Hello, DakotaMiller, and welcome to 3D printing beta! I'm wondering: which firmware are you using for your printer (you mention Repetier, but I'd just like to confirm this)? Also, have you manually tested your endstops using the M119-gcode? More info: http://reprap.org/wiki/Endstop

Comment: I did not use the code. However i did test it using the repetier host software on the computer by typing in a like 10mm for it to move and pressing the endstops myself. Also it moves away from the endstops when going to home.

Comment: The files i used for the frimware and software can be found on the site i mentioned.

Comment: If it moves away from the endstops when homing, try flipping the motor plugs where they connect to the mainboard  to make them run the opposite way. Then see if it homes properly.

Comment: @Ryan I can due that but the circuit diagram say that it needs to be the way I put it together. If I were to flip those would it damage anything?

Comment: Flipping the motor plugs is 100% harmless and will reverse the direction the motors turn.

Comment: Sweet, I had read somewhere that when the guy was putting his together he kept frying the driver boards, but I must have miss understood. This will solve a whole bunch of problems. Plus it makes more sense that the printer would use the endstops to judge distance. Thank you so much Ryan!

Comment: @Ryan it worked! I kept thinking that it needed inverted in the code. Anyway if you post the answer ill mark it as the solution. Now i can move on to calibrating it.

Comment: I recently bought an ei3 from he3d .. what a joke.. I had similar issues with limit switches being ignored by the unit causing it to attempt self-destruction when hitting maximum limits.. I finally found a copy of the firmware which I recompiled using arduino builder, as it wouldnt terwith the standard arduino ide.. you have to configure firmware to disable software max limits, and enable maximum hardware limits.. they didnt program the controller properly.. now if i can figure out howto get filament to load i might print something.. ive been at this for almost two months.. I also bought the c

Comment: @Jason don't feel bad after I started printing with mine it took me almost a year to get the hang of calibrating it every time to have really good prints. Stick with it. I have since bought 2 other printers and one is ok, it was put togeather in factory and the other was even worse then the he3d printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some troubleshooting in the question comments, it appears that the issue here is the motors running the wrong way. This can be fixed EITHER by inverting the motor directions in firmware, OR by simply flipping the orientation of the motor plugs where they connect to the controller board. Flipping the plugs is an easy and quick way to reverse the phase of a stepper and thus reverse its direction of motion.